# What is Unity's true form?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Unity, the hive-minded alien from *Rick and Morty* appeared in *Season 2 Episode 3: Auto Erotic Assimilation*. She is shown to assimilate other species, however her true form is not revealed (as far as I remember).

So, what's Unity true form? Have the writers commented on it?

Answer (score 6):

Her true form is most likely a hive mind made of bunch of telepathic microorganisms who take over host's nervous system and marshal the body into production of more Unity, like a virus does to a cell. The yellow puke used in assimilation is most likely Unity in its true form. After assimilation, part of the microorganisms gets into the eyes, turning the normally white sclera yellow.

Once the inhabitants of the planet break Unity's control, they puke her onto the ground and there is a lot of puke. Once enough was puked out, their eyes immediately turn white again.

At one point Rick asks Unity if she can assimilate a giraffe, which means he is not sure, probably thanks to the size of the giraffe or maybe the strength of the giraffe's immune system. I assume that it is about the concentration of the "puke", or microorganisms in the host's body which decides if the host is assimilated or not. Too few and host's immune system is able to fight them off.

Answer (score 0):

**We don't know**

And we will likely never know. For the show, we can assume that her 'true' form is the woman with glasses and blue skin as this is the one we see the all episode and in the Rickstaverse video game.

However, in the commentary of the episode we know that she is written as a genderless character and that she has

> flat concentric nipple rings.

I can't get my hand on the commentary right now so I will likely double check, but for now, this is all we know about Unity's true form.

Comment: I assumed that the blue woman was her true form. But she's the presidentrice of the planet so, that choice was eliminated. However  your point from the commentary might be useful (of course, once you add the sources)

Comment: The blue woman is clearly a member of the planet's species that Unity is currently controlling. And clearly Rick does not recognise their appearance, despite knowing Unity intimately.